# Show and hide div tags remotely

Tags: php, css, pdf

Using [CSS Refresh](http://cssrefresh.frebsite.nl/) my friend made it possible to show and hide div tags remotely using PHP and 'fopen'. He is on holiday and un-contactable at the moment. The idea was that it altered the CSS file when a button was pressed.

The purpose of this is to show iframes with PDF inside on command remotely for an online meeting. The reason I am not using TeamViewer Meeting or something simular is because the internet connection I have to use is tedious. I thought loading PDFs in div tags would get it all downloaded and ready for the CSS file to change to show it.

It was working (with only a next slide button) before I tried adding a previous slide button:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'], $_POST['next']))
{
$slide = $_POST['next'];
$slide = $_POST['previous'];
$slide_next = $slide + 1;
$slide_previous = $slide - 1;
$slide_current = $slide;
header("Location: next.php?slide=".$slide_next."");



} else {
if(isset($_GET['slide']))
{
$slide_next = $_GET['slide'];
}
else
{
$slide_next = "2";
}
echo ('
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="'.$slide_next.'" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go to Slide '.$slide_next.'" />
</form>
');
}
$myFile = "../css/changer.css.";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("Can't open zee file - error woo woo error");
$stringData = "#content$slide_current {\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = " visibility: visible;\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "}\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = ".content:not(#content$slide_next) {\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = " visibility: hidden;\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = " height: 0px;\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "}\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

I can't get back to how it was when it was working because I changed it directly on the FTP where backups are stored by my friend and they are not accessible by me at the moment.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: start by renaming either your $slide = $_POST['next']; or
$slide = $_POST['previous']; if you leave it this way it only has a value from $_POST['previous'] since one is overwriting the other

Comment: How does it currently behave? is any of it working? change `header("Location: next.php?slide=".$slide_next."");` to `header("Location: next.php?slide=".$slide_next);`

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you, you need to change the visibility of some div elements in all of the browsers, that have your site opened, right? The way, that you've selected is very strange for that, you can use jQuery's ajax and setInterval for this.
For example:

PHP for users:

```
<?php 
$curSlide = file_get_contents("/tmp/slidenumber.txt");//Get current active slide
if (!isset($_POST['testSlideChange'])):
//If there are no POST var, saying that this is an ajax update request, output the HTML page to browser:
?>    
<div id="slide-1" class="slide <?php if($curSlide==1) echo 'visible'?>">Content of slide1</div>
<div id="slide-2" class="slide <?php if($curSlide==2) echo 'visible'?>">Content of slide2</div>
<div id="slide-3" class="slide <?php if($curSlide==3) echo 'visible'?>">Content of slide3</div>
<div id="slide-4" class="slide <?php if($curSlide==4) echo 'visible'?>">Content of slide4</div>
<?php else: //else, if we have POST-var, just return current slide as a number
echo $curSlide;
endif; ?>
```

CSS:

```
slide 
{ display:none; }

slide.visible
{  display:block; }
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //test for slide change every 1 second
    setInterval(testSlideChange,1000);
});

function testSlideChange()
{
    //make post ajax request
    $.post('http://my.web.site.com/this_page.php', {'testSlideChange' : 1} , function(data) {
       //if result slide hasn't got class "visible", lets take it from the visible one, and give to a new one.
       if (!$('#slide-' + data).hasClass('visible')
       {
       $('.slide.visible').removeClass('visible');
       $('#slide-' + data).addClass('visible');
       }
    }
}
```

To change slide at server side you have just write another number to a file /tmp/slidenumber.txt, it could be done by simple server php script or manually.

---

I've created an example of how it should work. 
Working example!

User page: http://kovka54.ru/test/index.php (user can see slides here)
Admin page: http://kovka54.ru/test/admin.php (admin can set active slide here)
Open this pages on a separate windows (for example, in two browsers) and watch, how user's slide is changed when you change slide in admin side.
The example consists of 3 files: index.php ,admin.php and slidenumber.txt (which contains just single number, at the begining it's "1" (without quotes).
content of index.php: http://pastebin.com/zge3MbAQ, content if admin.php: http://pastebin.com/J5eDEbSe

Comment: I've put this all together. It shows all of the divs, not just the one specified in the txt. http://86.13.162.21/new_meeting/

Comment: did you added css in <style> tags ? your nginx gave me a 404 error

Comment: No, I put it in a separate CSS file. It should be back up now.

Comment: Edited my answer, watch to the bottom of it :)